# Reading data from multiple sensors without repeating the code for each device

Tags: labview

I have several pressure sensors in my setup and I read the data into labview. Is it possible to do this without writing the initialization code for each device seperately? It is exactly the same for each sensor...

Comment: Create a subVI that takes in the physical address of a pressure sensor as input and outputs the data. Alternatively, you can vectorize your code and just read all the data in a FOR loop, passing in an array of physical addresses and reading out an array of data.

Comment: Welcome to SO please check out [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance before submitting further questions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Adrian already answered to your question but I'd like to provide some more details.

I'd suggest that you create a subVI. Basically, you will have a piece of code where you define inputs and outputs and how to manipulate them. Then you can re-use whenever you need (similar to a function in other programming languages). Here is the [official NI guide](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA03q000000YK4VCAW&l=it-IT), where you can find all you need.